# Looping through csv file to create smaller file for action, loop not activating

Tags: python, loops, csv, loading, file-writing

The following code is meant to loop through a large csv file, take a block of 20 observations at a time, and load them into a smaller file, which will than be used for geocoding.  Loop does not seem to be running, and have run out of ideas why (nothing past the first row_count gets printed, except end)

```
SalesLoad = open('C:\Users\DillonSaxe\Real Estate\Chi address 2000-2015.csv')
Sales = csv.reader(SalesLoad)
Storage = []
row_count = sum(1 for row in Sales)
print row_count
for row in Sales:
    if Sales.line_num == 1:
        Header = row
        print header
    elif Sales.line_num%20 != 0 and Sales.line_num != row_count:
        Storage.append(row)
    else:
        Storage.append(row)
        print row
        TempLoad = open('C:\Users\DillonSaxe\Real Estate\Temp Geocode File.csv', 'wb')
        TempGeocode = csv.writer(TempLoad)
        TempGeocode.writerow(Header)
        for item in Storage:
            TempGeocode.writerow(item)
        TempLoad.close()
SalesLoad.close()
print 'Done'
```

Comment: Just an advice - please use lowercase names for your pointers (variables) - "sales_load" and not "SalesLoad", "sales" and not "Sales", etc...

Comment: Another advice: Never ever use spaces in Folder & Filenames, this only leads to issues.

Comment: SalesLoad = open('C:\\Users\\DillonSaxe\\Real Estate\\Chi address 2000-2015.csv')

Answer (score 0):

The line `row_count = sum(1 for row in Sales)` puts your reader at the bottom of the file. Add `SalesLoad.seek(0)` right after that line, or refactor your loop to not require the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use enumerate to test line number and iterate file once

```
  with open('C:\Users\DillonSaxe\Real Estate\Chi address 2000-2015.csv', 'rb') as f
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    storage = [line for idx, line in enumerate(reader) if idx%20]

  with open('C:\Users\DillonSaxe\Real Estate\Temp Geocode File.csv', 'wb') as f
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(storage )

  print 'Done'
```